# ERROR: for saleor-platform_db_1 a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: string, byte

ERROR: for saleor-platform_db_1  a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: I am running >>$ docker-compose run --rm api python3 manage.py migrate

Comment: Please add the whole error trace-back to your question. Also add code where you think the error might be occurring. Please also tag your question properly so that people may find it. I assume you are using python with Django and Saleor, add the following tags: `python`, `django`, `saleor`